# Spatial join list lat,lon and multipolygon Python

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, shapely, fiona

I have a dataframe with lat, lon columns in WGS84.

[image]

I also have a multipolygon layer (GeoJSON, I can also convert it to a SHP) with all countries' boundaries, where the name of the country is in the attribute table.

[image]

I would like to add to the dataframe a column where for each lat, lon I'll have the country name.

What would be the efficient way to do that (assuming I have 2000 lat lon pairs)?

UPDATE:

Thanks to @BERA I've created this function:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

df_countries = gpd.read_file(r"C:\countries.geojson")


def get_countries(df, lat_col, lon_col,df_countries):
    df_latlon = df[[lat_col,lon_col]].copy()
    df_latlon['Coordinates'] = list(zip(df_latlon[lon_col], df_latlon[lat_col]))
    df_latlon['Coordinates'] = df_latlon['Coordinates'].apply(Point)
    df_latlon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_latlon, geometry='Coordinates')
    df_latlon = df_latlon.set_crs(epsg=4326)
    df_latlon = gpd.sjoin(df_latlon, df_countries[['CNTRY_NAME','geometry']], how='left')
    return df_latlon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spatial Join:](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html)

```
import geopandas as gpd

dfpoints = gpd.read_file(r"C:\folder\bs_riks.shp")
dfpolys = gpd.read_file(r"C:\folder\ak_riks.shp")

df = gpd.sjoin(dfpoints, dfpolys, how='left')
#or: df = gpd.sjoin(dfpoints, dfpolys[['CNTRY_NAME','geometry']], how='left') #If you dont want all attributes from the polygons
```

If you have a pandas df of the coords, create geopandas like this: [Creating a GeoDataFrame from a DataFrame with coordinates](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html)

Comment: My lat lon are not in a SHP file, they are in two separate columns in a pandas dataframe

Comment: Convert the pandas df to a geopandas using the lat longs

Comment: can you please add it to the code in your answer so I'll mark it as correct?